# prevent rounding off of timestamp in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, rounding

I have a MySQL table with a single field of type TIMESTAMP.
When I insert a timestamp into the table, it is getting rounded off.

For example - if I do a

```
insert into tablename (time) values ("2014-08-25 23:59:59.587");
```

and then I do a

```
select * from tablename;
```

I get

```
2014-08-26 00:00:00
```

This is causing a bug in my code where I use the timestamp of the last record to determine where a new day has started.

How do I ensure that the fractional part gets stored as it is?
(or if it is getting stored correctly, then how do I retrieve it - (using Java))

I am using MySQL 5.6.16 and Java 8 
(although the problem does not require java and can be verified from the command line)

When using Java,

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


public class DBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection dbConn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demod?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8", "dawon","1111");
            Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT TEST FROM TIME;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("TEST");
            System.out.println("time" + ts.toString() + " " + rs.getTimestamp("TEST"));
            //both print out the rounded off value
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of [MySQL 5.6.4 the support for fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) is included in `Time`, `DateTime` and `TimeStamp` data types.

Your version should support it, you just need to detail your column as follows:

> To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the
>   syntax type_name(fsp), where type_name is TIME, DATETIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP, and fsp is the fractional seconds precision. For example:
>
> CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6)); The fsp value, if given,
>   must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no
>   fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0. (This differs
>   from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility with previous
>   MySQL versions.)

You should read the full article since it has more information about it.

**Update**

It worked for me here using the following command:

```
/* The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6 */
CREATE TABLE tablename (columnname TIMESTAMP(3));
```

Not a big deal but current version of the Workbench seems to be missing the support for that feature in the "create table" interface. I had to use the direct command to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

[Posting to save time for others]

I faced a similar problem with mysql/aurora.

I was trying to use new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(createdOn) in the queries, but found out that SimpleDateFormat simply drops additional fields.

Hibernate's default mapping of Date fields to MySQL DateTime columns (using the annotation @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)) was rounding off the milliseconds.

In order to generate consistent queries i had to implement rounding off myself while using SimpleDateFormat.

Example round off code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(this.getCreatedOn());
if (cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) >= 500 ) {
  System.out.println("Round off milliseconds to seconds");
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 1);
}
```

Usage in queries:

createdOn = "'" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(roundedCreatedOn)+ "'"